# Memory leak using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, memory-leaks, memory-leak-detector, objgraph

I am using `pandas.DataFrame` in a multi-threaded code (actually a custom subclass of `DataFrame` called `Sound`). I have noticed that I have a memory leak, since the memory usage of my program augments gradually over 10mn, to finally reach ~100% of my computer memory and crash.

I used [objgraph](http://mg.pov.lt/objgraph/) to try tracking this leak, and found out that the count of instances of `MyDataFrame` is going up all the time while it shouldn't : every thread in its `run` method creates an instance, makes some calculations, saves the result in a file and exits ... so no references should be kept.

Using `objgraph` I found that all the data frames in memory have a similar reference graph :

[image]

I have no idea if that's normal or not ... it looks like this is what is keeping my objects in memory. Any idea, advice, insight ?

Comment: Is it possible to include a short code snippet to replicate this?

Comment: Did you try to run manually the garbage collector ? If you have circular references, this could be required to release the memory. `import gc;  gc.collect()`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Confirmed that there's some kind of memory leak going on in the indexing infrastructure. It's *not* caused by the above reference graph. Let's move the discussion to GitHub (SO is for Q&A):

https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2659

EDIT: this actually appears to not be a memory leak at all, but has to do with the OS memory allocation issues perhaps. Please have a look at the github issue for more information

Comment: Ok ... collecting manually with gc seems to actually do the trick. I will confirm when I'm sure about that.

Comment: is there a reason why gen 2 gc was not running automagically by the Python runtime?