# Python DataFrame memory leak when using the at method

Tags: python, dataframe, memory-leaks

I am iterating over a python DataFrame

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    ...
    if condition:
        df.at[index, 'col'] = newValue
```

and every time `df.at` executes, my memory increases a little.

I am iterating over a one million row DataFrame so the machine runs out of memory and crashes.

A few observations:

- If I do not update the df, the memory does not surge, so the memory leak is due to the update using the `at` method
- I have tried breaking down the df in several chunks and calling `gc.collect()` after each chunk, or trying `del df_chunk_i` then `gc.collect()` but the memory is not released
- I have seen some other somewhat related SO questions that propose to do `inplace=True` but I can't see that applicable here

Is there an alternative that prevents the memory leak?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Memory leak using pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14224068/memory-leak-using-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Thank you for the reference RoseGod. gc.collect() seems to "fix" that issue (according to the github thread) but it does not fix the above issue.

Comment: If you make a minimal reproducible example, it will be easier to answer your question.

Comment: Tim, thank you for the suggestion which actually solved my problem...
I tried to reproduce the problem by creating a dataframe of random variables and the issue did not happen.
In my original problem i was updating my dataframe by adding percentages as strings, so after converting everything to floats instead of strings the memory leak disapeared... So by dealing with floats instead of strings I do not have that problem anymore

Answer (score 0):

The memory leak only appeared when using a string type in the dataframe, when using floats the memory leak disapeared.

I was initially adding strings to the dataframe and those strings were percentages as strings, e.g. 17% instead of 0.17. after moving to floats it all worked as expected